# how fix dependency error Project build error: dependencies cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar is missing

Tags: java, maven, openfeign

I have pom.xml in eclipse java for build simple Rest web service in java, but that dependency show error, I have trying and I have add version and update project still error in dependency, how can I fix it?............

this is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bsm</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-scheduler-decrypt-file</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-scheduler-decrypt-file</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my error dependencies

Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:jar is missing.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot-starter-parent as parent? If possible, please update your question with complete pom file.

Comment: yes I have updated @Smile

Comment: Try out steps mentioned in Harsh Mishra's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things I think you could try:

1.
Put the literal value of the version in the child pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>

</dependency>
```

2. Clear your .m2 cache normally located C:\Users\user.m2\repository. I would say I do this pretty frequently when I'm working in maven. Especially before committing so that I can be more confident CI will run. You don't have to nuke the folder every time, sometimes just your project packages and the .cache folder are enough.

If point 1 not works then
add this below after properties tag in your pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Can I delete all the contents of the file in the folder? @Harsh Mishra

Comment: Yes, try to add dependenciemanagement tag first in your pom. If it doesn't work then   delete the folder. mvn install will download the folder again.